# Solr special character search on person name

Tags: solr, lucene

I am a newbie to Solr. I have indexed people name in my collection as below.

When searching for a name like Àlvarez Rubén,I am unable to retrieve the results.I tried escaping using / however I didnt get the correct result.Please help

Comment: check filters you used in schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt](https://github.com/lmjabreu/solr-conftemplate/blob/master/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt) before Tokenizing your incoming values.

```
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
```